# Show QDialog on the currently active Space on OS X

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt4

I am currently working on an application that prompts the user when some task has completed, by popping up a dialog (think something along the lines of Growl).

If I start an operation on one space, then move to a different space, when the operation completes I am forced back to the first (initial) space. I believe this is caused by the QDialog getting focus, although this is just a hypothesis.

Is there any way to make a QDialog show() on the currently active space?

**EDIT** It seems that if I set the window flag Qt::Popup, the dialog behaves almost exactly like I want. That is, it shows up on the currently active space. However, it also grabs input and prevents the user from interacting with the other parts of the application. Furthermore, should it lose focus, it disappears entirely.

1. Can I set the popups to not grab input?
2. Can I make them stay on the screen, even if they lose focus?

Comment: I think you are seeing a bug in Qt.  Perhaps you can upgrade Qt to a new version?  (I'd find the Qt bug tracker report for it, but that site appears to be down right now)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Unfortunately I'm stuck with this version of Qt. The bug report would be really useful; happen to know what it was called so that I can find it later? Seems that I can sort of get the behavior I want by setting the windows flag Qt::popup. However it grabs input, and the windows disappear if you click on another window. Any ideas how to prevent the last two points, while maintaining the other attributes of the Qt::popup?

Comment: Don't use QDialog as it always tries to take input. Use QWidget with always on top and popup

Comment: @KamilKlimek it seems that Qt::Popup also blocks input. That is, if I have more than one popup, then the last one to show prevents you from interacting with the other popups. So not sure if that would work, but I'll test it out.